# Передать число из data аттрибута, полученного в одной функции, в другую, подставив его в querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom

Надо передать число, записанное в data аттрибуте переменной clicked (таргет клика, т.е какая-то кнопка) в другую функцию, при этом переданное число будет подставляться в document.querySelectorAll, чтобы получить массив из нужных элементов. При попытке передачи значения с помощью вызова второй функции в первой, возникает ошибка:
`Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.components__inputs-[object PointerEvent]' is not a valid selector.`
Помогите, пожалуйста, как передать нужное значение?

```
const getAnswer = document.querySelector(".done__btn");
const finalNumbers = document.querySelectorAll(".components__numbers");

function numbers(n) {
  const volume = document.querySelector(".volume__input").value;
  const concentration = document.querySelectorAll(`.components__inputs-${n}`);
  let arrValues = [];
  concentration.forEach((i) => {
    arrValues.push(Number(i.value));
  });
  }
}

getAnswer.addEventListener("click", numbers);

const choiceNut = document.querySelector(".choice");
const btnChoice = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const comcon = document.querySelectorAll('.components__concentration');

choiceNut.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const clicked = e.target.closest('.btn')
    if (!clicked) return
    btnChoice.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('btn__clicked'))
    clicked.classList.add('btn__clicked')
    comcon.forEach(c => c.classList.add('components__concentration_hidden'))
    document.querySelector(`.active-${clicked.dataset.tab}`).classList.remove('components__concentration_hidden');
    document.querySelector(`.active-${clicked.dataset.tab}`).classList.add('components__concentration_active');
    const numparameter = Number(clicked.dataset.tab);
    numbers(numparameter)
})
```

Comment: Как ты думаешь, что в функцию `numbers`  передаётся первым аргументом на этой строке `getAnswer.addEventListener("click", numbers);` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Но если поставить параметр к той функции, то js не будет определять его же?

Comment: Ты мой вопрос видел? Ответишь?

Comment: Ну если нет параметра в этой строчке, то наверно, ничего не передается

Comment: Да??? То есть ты не знаешь принцип работы применяемой функции `addEventListener` и как оно всё работает?

Comment: Странно, а в другом месте ты даже это применяешь....

Comment: Есть кнопка, по клику на нее, должна запускаться функция numbers, куда я хочу передать число, полученное из функции клика.

Comment: А когда вызывается событие клика (и любое другое событие), то что обычно "торчит" в вызываемой функции в виде параметра?

Comment: Обычно скобки стоят, event добавляют иногда? button.addEventListener('click', function() {})

Comment: "*event добавляют иногда*" --- а теперь прочитай сообщение об ошибке своё..... и подумай, что такое у тебя `n` при клике на `getAnswer`

Comment: n, получается, будет ивентом?

Comment: Получается, что так. Ведь ты передал функцию колбэка по ссылке, соответственно в неё функция передаёт свои аргументы

Comment: В другом месте ты вызываешь функцию с передачей числа...... соответственно, либо в функции `numbers` придётся проверять `n` на соответствие нужного типа и брать нужные данные в зависимсоти от типа, либо при клике на `getAnswer`  делать некие манипуляции, как это **уже было проделано** при клике на `choiceNut`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, понятно. А можно как-то этот ивент в число преобразовать? Или еще как-то получить число?

Comment: Хорошо, подумаю